# VB Excel (VSTO) - Export DataTable into Excel with Column Formats Based on Data Types

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

I've inherited a project in VB which is a language I'm not familiar with. The project is a custom Excel ribbon which exports data from stored procedures.

The issue is the current approach requires all values of the DataTable to be converted to a string and exported in a similiar way as a CSV. While this was intended to be the simpliest and fastest method to export the data, the end users then have to manually convert all non string columns to their correct formats after the data is populated. I'm trying to work out a way for each column of the exported data to be formatted according to data type.

**Current approach / original code:**

```
Public Sub PopulateExcel(QueryTable As Data.DataTable, SheetName As String)
    Dim wsActive As Excel.Worksheet
    wsActive = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()

    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    wb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook

    Dim intName As Integer = 1
    For Each Cell As DataColumn In QueryTable.Columns
        wsActive.Cells(3, intName) = Cell.ColumnName
        wsActive.Cells(3, intName).Font.Bold = True
        wsActive.Cells(3, intName).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 225, 242)
        intName += 1
    Next

    Dim intRow As Integer = 0
    Dim strData As String(,) = New String(QueryTable.Rows.Count - 1, QueryTable.Columns.Count - 1) {}
    For Each row As DataRow In QueryTable.Rows
        Dim intColumn As Integer = 0
        For Each Cell As DataColumn In QueryTable.Columns
            strData(intRow, intColumn) = row(Cell).ToString()
            intColumn += 1
        Next
        intRow += 1
    Next

    wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, 1), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, QueryTable.Columns.Count)).Value = strData
    wsActive.Columns.AutoFit()
    wsActive.Rows.AutoFit()
```

I've tried two solutions with little joy:

**1) Perform the export within the *QueryTable* loop with no string conversion.**

This works but has a considerable impact on performance as it is assigning the cell values one at a time.

```
    Dim intRow As Integer = 4
    For Each row As DataRow In QueryTable.Rows
        Dim intColumn As Integer = 1
        For Each Cell As DataColumn In QueryTable.Columns
            wsActive.Cells(intRow, intColumn) = row(Cell)
            intColumn += 1
        Next
        intRow += 1
    Next

    wsActive.Columns.AutoFit()
    wsActive.Rows.AutoFit()
```

**2) Change column formats after the data is export based on column name. I've not had any luck with this.**

In the below example I tried exporting the data first and while creating the columns names, I've tried to find any columns with 'Qty' in the name and convert the column format to a number format.

```
    Dim intRow As Integer = 0
    Dim strData As String(,) = New String(QueryTable.Rows.Count - 1, QueryTable.Columns.Count - 1) {}
    For Each row As DataRow In QueryTable.Rows
        Dim intColumn As Integer = 0
        For Each Cell As DataColumn In QueryTable.Columns
            strData(intRow, intColumn) = row(Cell).ToString()
            intColumn += 1
        Next
        intRow += 1
    Next

    wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, 1), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, QueryTable.Columns.Count)).Value = strData
    wsActive.Columns.AutoFit()
    wsActive.Rows.AutoFit()

    Dim intName As Integer = 1
    For Each Cell As DataColumn In QueryTable.Columns
        wsActive.Cells(3, intName) = Cell.ColumnName
        If Cell.ColumnName.Contains("Qty") Then
           wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count, intName)).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)"
        End If
        wsActive.Cells(3, intName).Font.Bold = True
        wsActive.Cells(3, intName).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 225, 242)
        intName += 1
    Next
```

I feel like there must be a better way to solve this issue. Any help or advice would be great.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've persevered with option 2. The column format is decided from the name of the column when adding the column names to the worksheet. Still don't think this is the best approach but it works for now.

```
        Dim intName As Integer = 1
    For Each Cell As DataColumn In QueryTable.Columns
        wsActive.Cells(3, intName) = Cell.ColumnName
        If Cell.ColumnName.Contains("Qty") Then
            wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).NumberFormat = "General"
            wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).Value = wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).Value
        End If
        If Cell.ColumnName.Contains("Value") Then
            wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).Value = wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).Value
        End If
        If Cell.ColumnName.Contains("Rate") Then
            wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).NumberFormat = "#,##0.0000"
            wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).Value = wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).Value
        End If
        If Cell.ColumnName.Contains("Percentage") Then
            wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).NumberFormat = "#,##0.0000"
            wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).Value = wsActive.Range(wsActive.Cells(4, intName), wsActive.Cells(QueryTable.Rows.Count + 1, intName)).Value
        End If
        wsActive.Cells(3, intName).Font.Bold = True
        wsActive.Cells(3, intName).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 225, 242)
        intName += 1
    Next

    wsActive.Columns.AutoFit()
    wsActive.Rows.AutoFit()
```